# Single word for "crucial, but often overlooked"

Tags: single-word-requests

> This side pursuit, however, is important, as it influences my approach
>   to teaching in a **crucial, but often overlooked**, manner.

Is there a single word that would work the same way as "crucial, but often overlooked"?

Comment: Sounds like the *Unsung Hero* badge.

Comment: I don't mean to be snippy, but what's wrong with "crucial, but often overlooked"? A lot of these "single word" requests apparently expect there to be a single word to describe every possible concept. Like, "Is there a single word to describe a person who is wearing a blue shirt while riding on a bicycle on his way home from work at a restaurant that serves pancakes and who must swerve to avoid hitting a dog named Rover that is blind in one eye?"

Comment: Seriously, even if there were such a word, would it add anything to OP's sentence that *"in a manner that's often overlooked"* doesn't convey? He's already said the side pursuit is *"important"*. If that's not strong enough, just change it to *"crucial"*.

Comment: Why don't we just get away from these "single word requests?" At least the problem becomes somewhat interesting if you put a bit effort and research into the question. These one-sentence *"I need a word meaning..."* crossword solvers are rarely a good use of this site. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Unacclaimed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unacclaimed)* and its [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/unacclaimed) or *[underestimated](http://thesaurus.com/browse/underestimated)* and its [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/underestimated) might be the best single-word fits.  I personally like *underrated*.

However, in your example, a single word would probably not be the most appropriate, since *crucial* is the only reason the "side pursuit" is important, not *overlooked*.  The side pursuit is not important for being underrated, so you wouldn't want to replace "crucial, but overlooked" with any single word that has the connotation of being overlooked.

Comment: Partially fitting, but they don't convey that something is crucial.